# Rails Neo4j neo4j.config.session_path is deprecated, please use neo4j.config.session.path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j

I cannot understand this error `neo4j.config.session_path is deprecated, please use neo4j.config.session.path.` I get this in the myspec file during the testing. I updated Neo4j to version 9 from 7 and now I have this deprecation. I cannot understand what I should do because nowhere I cannot find the line is deprecated. I'm getting the error in the next lines of code:

```
describe "Edit Access" do

before :all do
  Amendment.delete_all
  a = Amendment.create(cid: "X1", namespace: "http://www.example.com", property: "question",
                       study_value: "ADEF", default_value: "A1", datatype: "string")
  a = Amendment.create(cid: "X1", namespace: "http://www.example.com", property: "enabled",
                       study_value: "true", default_value: "true", datatype: "boolean")
  a = Amendment.create(cid: "Y1", namespace: "http://www.example.com", property: "enabled",
                       study_value: "false", default_value: "true", datatype: "boolean")
  ua_create
end

after :all do
  Amendment.delete_all
  ua_destroy
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should find `neo4j.config.session_path` defined somewhere in your app.  Maybe search / grep for it?  The places I would expect to find it are:

config/application.rb
config/environments/development.rb
config/environments/test.rb
config/environments/production.rb

Separately, I would make sure to read the [upgrade guide](http://neo4jrb.readthedocs.io/en/9.0.x/UpgradeGuide.html) for issues that may come up upgrading from 7.x to 8.x/9.x